# Why can't float represent pow(2., 60.) correctly?

Tags: visual-c++, floating-point

From [Computer Representation of Floating Point Numbers](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring01/V22.0421-001/extract.pdf) I have learnt the floating point representation of computer.
According to the tutorial, for 32-bit float, the smallest positive normalized
number that can be stored is 2^(-126)，and the largest normalized number is (2-2^(-23))*2^(127) ≈ 2^(128). However, the precision is limited by the 23-bit significand.

In my opinion, the 32-bit float can represent 2^60 without any error, because:

1. The sign: 1
2. The exponent: 10111011 (decimal 187 i.e. 60+127)
3. The significand: 0000 ... 0000 (23 zeros)

It is totally enough to use the exponent and the hidden bit (1) of significand to represent 2^60.

My test code are as following (VS2013 + win10):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    union
    {
        float input;   // assumes sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)
        int   output;
    }    data;

    data.input = pow(2., 60.);

    std::bitset<sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT>   bits(data.output);


    std::cout << "Total: " << bits << std::endl;


    cout << "Sign: " << bits[31] << endl << "Exponent: ";

    for (int i = 30; i > 22; i--)
    {
        cout << bits[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "Significand: ";

    for (int i = 22; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << bits[i];
    }
    cout << endl;


    cout.precision(20);
    cout << data.input << endl;
    printf("%f", data.input);
}
```

And I get the output:

```
    Total: 01011101100000000000000000000000
    Sign: 0
    Exponent: 10111011
    Significand: 00000000000000000000000
    1152921504606847000
    1152921504606847000.000000
```

I print the binary representation and it's correct. But I am puzzled why the last three digits are zero. The correct output should be 1152921504606846976.

Furthermore, I change the code as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 65; i++)
    {
        union
        {
            float input;   // assumes sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)
            int   output;
        }    data;

        data.input = pow(2, i);

        std::bitset<sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT>   bits(data.output);


        cout.precision(20);
        cout << i << ": " << data.input << endl;
        //printf("%f\n", data.input);
    }

}
```

And the output is:

```
1: 2
2 : 4
3 : 8
    ......
55 : 36028797018963968
56 : 72057594037927936
57 : 144115188075855870
58 : 288230376151711740
59 : 576460752303423490
60 : 1152921504606847000
61 : 2305843009213694000
62 : 4611686018427387900
63 : 9223372036854775800
64 : 18446744073709552000
```

The zero begin to occur from 2^57. Can anyone tell me why this happen?

Comment: `printf` and `cout` only bother to print as many significant digits as is necessary to parse the text back to the original value. Presumably, `1152921504606847000` is closer to 2^60 than to any other number representable in a `float`.

Comment: BTW there's a dedicated function for calculating powers of 2, its name is `ldexp` and it is *much* faster then `pow(2.0, x)`.  The relationship is `pow(2.0, x) == ldexp(1.0, x)`

Comment: And your program has undefined behavior as written -- better use `memcpy` to get the bit representation of your float into an integer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: `printf` and `cout` may produce many more digits—variations in behavior after the 17th digit (in this case) are due to implementation choices, not due to the specification of `printf` and `cout` generally.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I guess the right formulation would be "One shouldn't expect `printf` or `cout` to print any more significant digits than are necessary to parse the number back."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a failure of `float` to represent 2<sup>60</sup> correctly. It is a failure of Microsoft’s software to convert 2<sup>60</sup> to decimal correctly (that is, the failure is in the formatting code, not in the `float` arithmetic, although Microsoft’s `pow` implementation was also inaccurate previously). The software you are using produces only 17 decimal digits, regardless of the actual value involved. The same program compiled with Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5) produces:

```
55: 36028797018963968
56: 72057594037927936
57: 144115188075855872
58: 288230376151711744
59: 576460752303423488
60: 1152921504606846976
61: 2305843009213693952
62: 4611686018427387904
63: 9223372036854775808
64: 18446744073709551616
```

Microsoft’s behavior is permitted by the C standard but is, of course, not good mathematically.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! I try `float a = pow(2., 57); float b = a / 2; cout.precision(20); cout << b<< endl;` I get 72057594037927936 again, which confirms your statement.